# Typescript in VSCode cant find modules that actually exist

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx

VSCode is showing errors for modules that actually exist. Even though these errors exist in vscode; TS in the terminal is working fine.

> Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal/observable/of'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

Other devs in the same repo have the problem too so maybe that indicates something wrong with tsconfig.ts? What tools or methods can be used to hunt down this prob?

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@nx-fornida/amz": ["libs/amz/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/client-logic/orders": [ "libs/client-logic/orders/src/index.ts" ],
      "@nx-fornida/common-libs/error-handler": [ "libs/common-libs/error-handler/src/index.ts" ],
      "@nx-fornida/client-logic/amz-reports": [ "libs/client-logic/amz-reports/src/index.ts" ],
      "@nx-fornida/components": ["libs/frontend/components/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/custom-collections-node": [ "libs/custom-collections-node/src/index.ts" ],
      "@nx-fornida/frontend-auth": ["libs/frontend/auth/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/frontend-common": ["libs/frontend/common/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/frontend-core": ["libs/frontend/core/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/frontend-layout": ["libs/frontend/layout/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/frontend-themer": ["libs/frontend/themer/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/interface/amz": ["libs/interfaces/amz.interface"],
      "@nx-fornida/interface/bigcommerce": ["libs/interfaces/bc.interface"],
      "@nx-fornida/interface/customcollections": [ "libs/interfaces/customcollections.interface.ts" ],
      "@nx-fornida/interface/errorhandler": [ "libs/interfaces/errorhandler.interface" ],
      "@nx-fornida/interface/parts": ["libs/interfaces/parts.model"],
      "@nx-fornida/interface/retail": ["libs/interfaces/retail.interface"],
      "@nx-fornida/selling-partners-sdk": [ "libs/selling-partners-sdk/src/index.ts" ],
      "@nx-fornida/suggested-retail": ["libs/suggested-retail/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/ui": ["libs/frontend/ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@nx-fornida/views/amz-orders": [ "libs/frontend/views/amz-orders/src/index.ts" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have similar problem with shared library, it is set up in tsconfig.base.json but importing it in an app is failing with 'Cannot find module' error